# Subscribing within constructor of extended class does not work correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subject

I've built an abstract class called CoreButtonService which every ButtonService will extend. For example there are UserButtonService, MessageButtonService and so on. Those services are going to be injected into the respective component like UserComponent, MessageComponent and so on. In the constructor of the CoreButtonService I subscribed to another service called ButtonsService which is responsible for firing an event when any button within the ButtonModule has been clicked.

**CoreButtonService:**

```
export abstract class CoreButtonService<T extends CoreModel> extends CoreService {

    private backSource = new Subject<string>();
    private submitSource = new Subject<string>();
    back$ = this.backSource.asObservable();
    submit$ = this.submitSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private coreButtonsService: ButtonsService,
        private coreLanguageService: LanguageService,
        private coreLocation: Location) {
        super(coreLanguageService);
        this.coreButtonsService
            .buttonClicked$
            .subscribe(button => console.log(button)); // !!!!!!
    }

    // Buttons are going to be built down here ...

}
```

**ButtonsService:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ButtonsService {
    private button = new Subject<ButtonBase<any>>();
    buttonClicked$ = this.button.asObservable();
    constructor(private formService: FormService) { }

    clickButton(button: ButtonBase<any>): void {
        if (button.controlType === 'submit')
            this.formService.submitForm(button.parent);
        this.button.next(button);
    }
}
```

Let's assume I visit the page that includes the UserComponent, click a button and then do the same on the page of the MessageComponent. Technically there should be logged 2 buttons within the console. The button of the UserComponent and the button of the MessageComponent which I can identify by `button.parent`. But I get 2 buttons of MessageComponent.

When I save the sent parent within CoreButtonService and log it like the button, I get the expected values: 'MessageForm' for MessageComponent and 'UserForm' for UserComponent. But the values of `button.parent` are both the same. How is that possible?

I don't see the problem. May be it is because every ButtonService is doing the same subscription within the CoreButtonService and that's why each subscription / button is related to each other?

**UPDATE**

This is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2HAtIZ0qLlWfB5uDJCgt?p=preview) with the basic concept.

Comment: Tested and show `Object {key: "back", parent: "UserForm"}` when click on UserComponent, show `Object {key: "back", parent: "MessageForm"}` on MessageComponent. What gets wrong?

Comment: @Val That is strange. When I first click "back" on UserComponent it shows `Object {key: "back", parent: "UserForm"}`. When I navigate to MessageComponent and click "back" it shows `Object {key: "back", parent: "MessageForm"} Object {key: "back", parent: "MessageForm"}`. So it gets logged two times.

Comment: Do all the other visitors having the same logging behavior like @Val? And if yes, what can cause this behavior in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the mistake and it's a pretty silly one. Within the CoreComponent I unsubscribed like

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe;
}
```

instead of `unsubscribe()`. So the events went a little bit crazy. But thanks for help anyway.

Comment: was busy and hard to reply with mobile. your answer is great.

Comment: `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`. `this.subscription.unsubscribe` is a noop.

Answer (score 1):

To explain @user289520's solution in more detail:

- `Subscriptions`: Represents a disposable resource, such as the execution of an Observable. A Subscription has one important method, `unsubscribe`, that takes no argument and just disposes the resource held by the subscription.

You can collect subscriptions that you want to `unsubscribe` at once in `ngOnDestroy()`.

- `ngOnDestroy()`: Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

However apart from `this.subscription.unsubscribe;` you can also do this in a `foreach` loop shown as below:

```
this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
```

Why should you not forget to `unsubscribe()` in `angular.js`?

- Promises are eager and are executed immediately. Observables are not eager and are only executed when `subscribed` to.
- Promises are `asynchronous`. Observables can be either [synchronous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synchronous) or [asynchronous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asynchronous).
- Promises are expected to return only a single value (like a function). Observables can return zero, one or more (infinitely) values.